# Simplifying this in PHP

Tags: php, fuelphp

How can I simplify this with less code?

```
<?php
$items['link1'] = 'Link 1';
$items['link2'] = 'LInk 2';
$items['link3'] = 'Link 3';
?>

<?php foreach ($items as $url => $text): ?>
<?php $class = false; if (isset($active) and $active == $url) $class = array('class' => 'current'); ?>
<?php echo '<li>' . Html::anchor($url, $text, $class) . '</li>' ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And also, for some reason the "current" class is not showing when on the particular URL.

Thanks

Comment: Less? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do less with!?

Comment: I just added the rest.. sorry, thought I had it there.

Comment: Remove all the extra open and close tags.

Comment: Well, you could get rid of the redundant `<?php` and `?>` but I guess you left out some html in between there? Also, just because it’s in-line code does not mean you shouldn’t make the code readable and pretty. A few line breaks would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is less code:

```
<?php

$items=array(
  'link1' => 'Link 1',
  'link2' => 'LInk 2',
  'link3' => 'Link 3',
);

foreach ($items as $url => $text) {
  $class = false;
  if (isset($active) && $active == $url)
    $class = array('class' => 'current');
  echo '<li>' . Html::anchor($url, $text, $class) . '</li>';
}

?>
```

But since I don't know what it's supposed to do, I can't really help beyond pretty-printing it for you.  More details, please.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning it up.  Further, I'm just trying to add a "current" class to my a tags.. for example: <a class="current" href="..."> If I am on that particular link.. domain.com/link1